# Adding multiple objects to an ArrayList results in only the last item being added multiple times

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add objects to an ArrayList, but it seems that whenever I call the add method, the list is populated by only the last object that I add.

Here's how I add:

```
MyObject testObject1 = new MyObject();
testObject1.setType(0);
MyList.myList.add(testObject1);
MyObject testObject2 = new MyObject();
testObject2.setType(1);
MyList.myList.add(testObject2);
```

MyList is a class with a single ArrayList which is defined as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

MyObject is a class with some member variables and methods:

```
static int type;
public void setType(int inType) {
  type = inType;
}
```

I then list out the objects in MyList.myList as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<MyList.myList.size(); i++) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Type is " + MyList.myList.get(i).getType());
}
```

It lists 2 objects, but the type is always 1.

What's up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `setType` is `static`, which isn't associated with Object's state

```
MyObject.setType = 1;
```

remove `static` keyword from `setType` 's delcaration in `MyObject` class and set its value per instance

---

**See**

- [class member variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Hi, I made a typo in the original posted code. I didn't actually call MyObject.setType(), but called the instance's setType instead, i.e. testObject1.setType(0) and testObject2.setType(1)

Comment: post your setType method full body

Comment: Done. It's in the MyObject class.

Comment: its the same thing you are assigning value to `static` variable, which is not per object but per class loaded, so all the instances share values, please re read my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
static int type;
public void setType(int inType) {
  type = inType;
}
```

You should not be setting a static variable from an instance method.

```
int type;
public void setType(int inType) {
  type = inType;
}
```

Changing as above will fix your issue.